# Finding minimum of penalty-approximated quadratic problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

> Find the minimum of the following quadratic function
>
> $$ f_{\alpha}(x) := \frac{1}{2} x^T H x + c^T x + \frac{\alpha}{2}(b^Tx)^2 $$
>
> where matrix $H$ is symmetric and positive definite, and $\alpha \geq 0$.

I try to set gradient to zero and get

$$Hx+c+\alpha(b^Tx)b = 0$$

Now I have troubles to get $x$, because it is in the matrix multiplication and in the scalar product. Here some help would be useful.

The whole thing is actually a penalty approximation of the restricted problem to minimize

$$\text{minimize} \quad f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^THx+c^Tx \quad \text{ subject to } x^T c = 0$$

I may show that the sequence of minima of $f_{\alpha}(x)$ converges to the minimum $f(x)$ with growing $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes,  α≥0  this is is required by the algorithm

Comment: Since $b^Tx$ is a scalar, it can right-multiply vector $b$ instead. Hence, $$Hx + c + \alpha (b^Tx) b = Hx + c + \alpha b b^T x = (H + \alpha b b^T) x + c = 0$$ where matrix $H + \alpha b b^T$ is clearly symmetric and positive definite. Keep in mind that there is seldom a good reason to invert a matrix. Linear systems are solved using Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\frac 12(b^T x)^2 = \frac 12(x^T b)(b^T x)\Rightarrow \partial_x\frac 12(b^T x)^2 = b(b^T x)
$$

$$
\left(H+\alpha b b^T\right)x + c = 0\Rightarrow x = -\left(H+\alpha bb^T\right)^{-1}c
$$

Comment: thank you very much for help!