# Penalty-Approximated solution to quadratic program

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Find the minimum of the following quadratic function

$U(x) = \frac{1}{2}x'Qx -qx'R +\frac{\alpha}{2}(x'd -b)^2$

Where Q is a positive semi-definite symmetric matrix, $x,R,d$ are $Nx1$ vectors, and $q, \alpha$ and $b$ are scalars $>0$.

The problem is a penalty approximated solution to

$U(x) = \frac{1}{2}x'Qx -qx'R$

Such that $x'd=b$.

The solution is to set the gradient equal to 0, which I do here:

$Qx - qR +\alpha (x'd-b)d = 0$

It is here where I get stuck. I am not sure how to pull the x out  of $(x'd-b)d$.

Also, I'm assuming that I will be able to invert Q, or the matrix that becomes Q, to solve the program as the matrix is positive semi-definite and therefore is convex. Is this thinking on the right path?

A very similar question is asked here, but with b = 0:
[Finding minimum of penalty-approximated quadratic problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231640/finding-minimum-of-penalty-approximated-quadratic-problem)

Comment: I would have expected a term of the form $d d^T x$ in the gradient :-). Rewrite your gradient.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @copper.hat .  Because $x'd$ is a scalar, I may rewrite it as $d'x$ and then right multiply the $d$ to get $Qx - qR +\alpha d(d'x-b)$ I don't know how to deal with the scalar $b$ at this point.

Comment: So you get an equation $(Q+αdd')x=qR+αdb$ and have to make sure that $(Q+αdd')$ is regular.

Comment: I see, I can distribute $\alpha d$ and go from there. It is true that since Q is positive semi-definite symmetric matrix (a covariance matrix, infact) that adding a constant to it, $\alpha dd'$ keeps it regular and doesn't change the convexity of the function?

Comment: Yes, the sum of two convex functions is again convex. This procedure will only work if $Q$ has co-rank $1$, else you would need more compensating penalty terms.

Comment: Very helpful for me, @LutzL . I do not fully grasp your comment on co-rank, but it seems to me that if it did not have co-rank 1, it would not be invertible, and hence the solution to the equation would not exist. Perhaps I do know know how to show or explain that $(Q + \alpha dd')$ is regular, although intuitively is seems to make sense

Comment: Co-rank is the rank deficiency of the matrix, or the kernel dimension. Adding a dyadic product increases the rank by at most one, so to get full rank you need to start with co-rank 1 (or 0).